# Excel - previous sheet name when defining sourcedata for chart

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I am trying to write a macro to create a pivot table in a new sheet. I'm having problems eliminating the dependence on sheet names, as the names of my data changed daily, but the format does not.

My macro errors here with "Run-time error 438: Object doesn't support this property of method"

```
'create pivot table
Range("A1:J25").Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    ActiveSheet.Last & "!R1C1:R25C10", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14 _
    ).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:= _
    "PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
```

What can I replace "sheetx!R1C1:R25C10" with that doesn't rely on a name?

Comment: UPDATE: After looking a little closer at my code (I've been using the macro recorder) I noticed that the new sheet had not been selected yet. I removed the reference to a sheetname all together, and just referenced the cells. This works for now, but I'm still interested in the answer to my original question as I'm sure I will deal with that problem in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Glad you've got it working ... if the sheet name changes but the position of the sheet remains the same, you could reference by index:

```
Const DataSheetIndex As Integer = 1
Dim sourceData As String

sourceData = Worksheets(DataSheetIndex).Name & "!R1C1:R25C10"
```

Or if the name changes but at least has some consistency, e.g. initial characters, you could use the `Worksheets` collection ...

```
Dim ws As Worksheet

For Each ws In Worksheets

If (Left$(ws.Name, 4) = "test") Then

    sourceData = ws.Name & "!R1C1:R25C10"

End If

Next ws
```

And [a link](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/10-things/10-ways-to-reference-excel-workbooks-and-sheets-using-vba/967/) for different ways of referencing worksheets, in case one of those appears more appropriate for your use.

Comment: Thanks for answering the original question, and the link to the resources is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
Sub CreatePivot()

Dim dataSource, destination As String
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim data_sheet, new_sheet As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set data_sheet = wb.Sheets("my_data") 'assuming you have Sheet named "my_data"
Set new_sheet = wb.Sheets.Add 'add the sheet
new_sheet.Name = "my_pivot" 'Rename it

dataSource = data_sheet.Name & "!" & data_sheet.Range("A1:J25").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 'Set the source data, you can make this dynamic if you want
destination = new_sheet.Name & "!" & new_sheet.Range("A1").Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1) 'Set the destination which is the newly created sheet

'then add the pivot
wb.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
dataSource, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:=destination, TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion _
:=xlPivotTableVersion14

'take note that version differs depending on your Excel version

End Sub
```

Hope this gets you started.

Comment: I also appreciated your approach, this gives me a good example to reference when writing my own code instead of using the macro-recorder.

Comment: Glad it helped you in a way :)

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem and solved it by renaming the actual sheet first before creating pivot.

```
activesheet.name = "Data"
```

So in your case it would be:

```
Range("A1:J25").Select
activesheet.name = "Data" 
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Data!R1C1:R25C10", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14 _
.........
```

I hope this helps.